# Can't do an Animated menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw this reel https://www.instagram.com/p/CcyXukODe9D/
Done it as the video but it does not work with the animation. I think something with the JS is not working because the rest works ok.
Maybe I have to link the JavaScript in another way

```js
let cuadrado = document.querySelector(".cuadrado");

cuadrado.addEventListener("click", () =>
  cuadrado.classList.toggle("active"));
```

```css
.cuadrado {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  background-color: white;
  width: 48px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.active .line:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(12px) rotate(135deg);
}

.active .line:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.active .line:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-16px) rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Prueba menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <script src="animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="cuadrado">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work, check how and when you're loading your JS in your file

Comment: You actually don't need any JavaScript at all: you can attach the animation to a style rule for `:active` or use script-less DOM manipulation (e.g. `:checked`-trick with a hidden `<label>` once clicked)

Comment: How do you do it just with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `<script src="animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` right before your closing `</body>`. Also change it to `<script src="animation.js"></script>`. While you're at it, double-check the file name. So like this:

```
...
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>

<script src="animation.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Rather than moving the `<script>` to the `<body>` - instead _fix the script_ by wrapping its logic in a `DOMContentLoaded` event-listener, and adding `defer`.

Comment: @Dai only adding `defer` is enough as it loads the script only after everything else is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone that answerd. In fact it was working, i didn't notice the JS function was 'on click' and not on 'mouseover' as i thought.
Sorry for disturbing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).